# How to listen the Dependency property changes in WinRT?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

In WPF we can listen the Dependency property changes by using the below code.

```
 FlowDirectionProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGrid),
 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnFlowDirectionChanged));
```

But how to listen the changes in property in WinRT?

Comment: Could you please any one help me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a handler to get notify the changes for a dependency property.

use the below syntax

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(DependencyPropertyWatcher),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyChanged));

public event EventHandler PropertyChanged;

 public DependencyPropertyWatcher(DependencyObject target, string propertyPath)
 {
        this.Target = target;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
        this,
        ValueProperty,
        new Binding() { Source = target, Path = new PropertyPath(propertyPath), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
}
```

For additional details please go through this link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/flaviencharlon/archive/2012/12/07/getting-change-notifications-from-any-dependency-property-in-windows-store-apps.aspx